# data cleaning with read.csv

Tags: r, data-cleaning, read.csv

As a beginner, I'd like to ask you which is the more elegant/effective way to clean big .csv data: I've tried two kinds of solutions (found with `help()`, here and in the literature) but I'm not sure if there is something better (i.e. with loops?) you can suggest me.

My (not very R-friendly) .csv data (523 rows, 47 columns, here only the beginning):

```
;;;
;;;
;;;
Name;#1;#2;#3
Correction;;;          
Date;19.09.2016;19.09.2016;19.09.2016
Time;12:05:03;12:06:01;12:07:00
T_int [ms];806;800;884
Ev [lx];1,31E+03;1,35E+03;1,27E+03
Ee [W/sqm] (380-780nm);4,22E+00;4,38E+00;4,17E+00
;;;
;;;
Chrom. Coord.;;;           
x;0,3657;0,3642;0,3643
y;0,3842;0,3831;0,3833
u';0,2126;0,2121;0,2121
v';0,5026;0,502;0,5021
;;;
```

I'm interested in selecting only some information (about 450 of the 523 rows) and having at the end a transposed data frame like:

```
   Date       Time     Ev   # ...
V2 2016-09-19 12:05:03 1310 # ...
V3 2016-09-19 12:06:01 1350 # ...
V4 2016-09-19 12:07:00 1270 # ...
# [...]
```

The ways I tried are:

```
Date <- t(read.csv2("filename", nrows=1, skip=5, header=F)[,-1])
Time <- t(read.csv2("filename", nrows=1, skip=6, header=F)[,-1])
Ev <- t(read.csv2("filename", nrows=1, skip=8, header=F)[,-1])
# [...] (for all the about 450 choosen vectors!!!)
df <- data.frame(Date = Date, Time = Time, Ev = Ev) # ...
```

and

```
columns <- c(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, Date, Time, n6, Ev) # [...]
raw_csv <- t(read.csv2("filename", header=F, col.names = columns, colClasses = c(rep("NULL",5),rep("Date",2),"NULL","numeric")) # ...
df <- data.frame(raw_csv)
```

I'm feeling like I'm not able to find something better structured, avoiding i.e. to define 450 times separately what I'd like to have and where to find it.

In both cases I don't even reach my objective, because of lost spaces in the .csv, brackets and so on. Too much problems at the same time, I guess...

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: does the number of date/time matches with the number of rows for your data ?

Comment: Yes, at the end it should match with the number of rows of my final data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the ultimate form you'll need will be very dependent on the particulars of the file in question, for what you've presented here you can hack the data out without too much insanity:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_csv2(file, col_names = FALSE) %>% 
    filter(rowSums(!is.na(.)) > 0) %>% 
    magrittr::set_rownames(.[[1]]) %>% 
    select(-1) %>% 
    t() %>% 
    as_data_frame() %>% 
    type_convert(col_types = cols(Date = col_date('%d.%m.%Y')), 
                 locale = locale(decimal_mark = ','))

df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 12
#>    Name Correction       Date     Time `T_int [ms]` `Ev [lx]`
#>   <chr>      <chr>     <date>   <time>        <int>     <dbl>
#> 1    #1       <NA> 2016-09-19 12:05:03          806      1310
#> 2    #2       <NA> 2016-09-19 12:06:01          800      1350
#> 3    #3       <NA> 2016-09-19 12:07:00          884      1270
#> # ... with 6 more variables: `Ee [W/sqm] (380-780nm)` <dbl>, `Chrom.
#> #   Coord.` <chr>, x <dbl>, y <dbl>, `u'` <dbl>, `v'` <dbl>
```

---

Data

```r
file <- ";;;
;;;
;;;
Name;#1;#2;#3
Correction;;;          
Date;19.09.2016;19.09.2016;19.09.2016
Time;12:05:03;12:06:01;12:07:00
T_int [ms];806;800;884
Ev [lx];1,31E+03;1,35E+03;1,27E+03
Ee [W/sqm] (380-780nm);4,22E+00;4,38E+00;4,17E+00
;;;
;;;
Chrom. Coord.;;;           
x;0,3657;0,3642;0,3643
y;0,3842;0,3831;0,3833
u';0,2126;0,2121;0,2121
v';0,5026;0,502;0,5021
;;;"
```

Comment: Oh! That's actually much better, as it's actually a properly formatted (if still sideways) CSV instead of just unstructured text, so you can avoid the regex. See the edit.

Comment: Thank you very much! Working with the whole dataset I receive two messages. I don't understand the first one at all: `Using ',' as decimal and '.' as grouping mark. Use read_delim() for more control.`, then I have an `Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed` (the output of this instrument is not really R-friendly...). How can I get rid of Variable names and rows (i.e. `CCT [K]` comparing more than one time?

Comment: The first is just a message (not an error) from `read_csv2` telling you what it's doing. The second is a problem which could be dodged by making it a matrix first, but it's a better idea to just address the problem by changing it to `magrittr::set_rownames(make.unique(.[[1]]))`. You're still probably going to have to clean up more afterwards, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Now I have to exactely understand/learn what you've done and make some further step like eliminate the columns without data (i.e. `Correction`). P.S. I'm feeling like I just talked with a demigod. I was working at this issue since two days... :)

Comment: You can get rid of the all-`NA` columns by tacking on `select_if(funs(any(!is.na(.))))` or just by setting the 0 in the `filter` above to 1 as long as every variable with actual data is named. There are really a lot of different ways to do all these things; what's here is just my tidyverse-heavy habits.

Comment: Yes! I solved with the higher `filter` after reading `help(filter)`, `help(rowSums)` and `help(is.na)` :) I think I'm practicing right. Thanks again!